# how I can add push notification service to my application?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

here I add parse library to my application. but in my  main activity i faced an error with parse.initialize .

```
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, "id",   
        "id");

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MyActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: Please post the errors. Also, I don't know if what you posted is private, but you might consider carefully if you posted something private on a public form...

Answer (score 1):

You're using initialize in your activity, you should rather try in your Application class, from the docs

> The recommended way is to put a call to Parse.initialize in your
>   Application's onCreate method.

An example:

```
 import android.app.Application;
 import com.parse.Parse;

 public class MyApplication extends Application {

   public void onCreate() {
     Parse.initialize(this, "your application id", "your client key");
   }

 }
```

you should also add to your manifest

```
<application
        android:name="YourPackageName.MyApplication"
</application>
```